# Remote debug on JBoss AS7.4 as windows service is not happening

Tags: jboss, windows-services, remote-debugging

I'm looking for the right way to configure JBoss remote debugging in situations where JBoss is installed as a Windows service. I'm working with JBoss 7.4 / EAP 6.3.0, if that makes a difference. I think what I'm getting wrong is how to add JAVA_OPTS in the context of jbosssvc.exe. Once I can do that, I can add the usual remote debugging options: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n`.

I first did the obvious: uncomment the JAVA_OPTS line containing the above args in standalone.conf.bat. I saw no logging indicating that the server was listening on port 8787, and could not connect to the remote process in Eclipse (the attempt timed out). Then I tried to add a similar line in service.bat, but I think that was a misguided effort, and in any case had no effect.

So what's the correct way to do this? (And if different: what will work?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, mystery solved. I had requested that a colleague open port 8787 on that server, and he did just that - on the wrong server. This actually works folks!